# Casting Class.forName("java.lang.String") / 'Class.forName("some_str_var")' to Class<String>: why former produces unchecked compiler warning?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

This line of code

```
 Class<String> cls =  (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

Gives compiler warning `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<String>`

Also, according to API definition it returns returns `Class<?>`:

```
Class<?> Class.forName(String arg)
```

**I do not understand why conversion from `Class<?>` to `Class<String>` is treated as unchecked** (that is compiler cannot check if such cast is possible while compiling).

If it was

```
Class<String> cls =  (Class<String>) Class.forName("some_str_var");
```

I could understand that compiler cannot know return type of Class.forName() at compile time (*because argument is a variable, not a literal*) and in runtime type information is erased.

But `Class.forName("java.lang.String")` is obviuosly `Class<?>` during compilation (and `cls` variable in LHS is still `Class<String>`), no type information is erased yet (compiler sees source code, not byte-code with erased type-info), and compiler can check everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't give any special treatment to the string constant `"java.lang.String"` in this call:

```
Class.forName("java.lang.String")
```

`Class.forName` is just one of the many methods, just as the parameter passed to it is just one of the many strings.

So the following two are the same for the compiler (as far as the return type is concerned):

```
String className = "java.lang.String";
Class<String> stringClass = Class.forName(className);
```

And

```
Class<String> stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

The compiler doesn't inspect the constant argument to infer that this will necessarily be `Class<String>`. If you want to get `Class<String>` in a type-safe manner, you have to use:

```
Class<String> stringClass = String.class
```

Comment: I think it's important to emphasise it's what the Java Language Specification specifies, not whatever any particular implementation of a compiler decides to do. Go read and understand the JLS and then consider whether it needs to be made more complicated. Also there is a separation of language and library - this isn't classic BASIC.

Answer (score 1):

The class represented by the string `"java.lang.String"` happens to be available at compile time because it is part of the standard library. So the compiler could, in principle, execute the `class.forName()` and check that the returned class matches the type declaration.

But this would be a special case. In general, the string might specify a class that is not available at all at compile time - it might be in a pluggable library that is loaded dynamically at runtime, for example.

So the compiler is just taking the simplest, most general approach. Compilers are complex, and the designers often choose not to add more complexity that will only benefit a few special cases.

I also suspect that the possibility of custom classloaders might make it challenging to implement this checking; the classes available at compile time are probably not *guaranteed* (by the Java Language Specification) to be those available at runtime, even for the standard library - even though they would *normally* be the same.